# Calculating time complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to calculate the time complexity of a recursive algorithm and I think I've almost got it. Here's the psuedocode I've been looking at:

```
long pow( long x, int n ) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)
    return x;
    if(isEven(n))
        return pow(x, n / 2 ) * pow(x, n / 2);
    else
        return x * pow(x * x, n / 2);
}
```

isEven merely determines whether or not the integer passed to it is even or not, and for the point of this example, operates in constant time.

So, if n = 0 or n = 1, it operates it has constant time operation, like this:
f(n) = C0. 
However, when n > 1, it should operate like so:
f(n)= f(n-1) + f(n-1) + C1 when n is even and f(n)= f(n-1) + 1 when n is odd, correct? Or should it be: f(n)= f(n/2) + f(n/2) + C1 when n is even and f(n)= f(n/2) + 1 when n is odd?

I've been looking at a lot of examples. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709106/time-complexity-of-a-recursive-algorithm) is one I've found very helpful. My problem stems from there being two recursive calls when n is even. I'm not fully sure what to do here. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This newbie question is well asked.

Comment: Is it intentional that you are making two recursive calls to `pow(x, n / 2)` with the same arguments? You could just do `long r = pow(x, n / 2);  return r * r;` and then not only is it more efficient, but the analysis is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).  You can treat this as a "divide and conquer" algorithm.

The end result is that with the two recursive calls in place, you end up with a worst case O(n) runtime.  E.g. pow(x, 4) calls pow(x, 2) twice, and pow(x, 1) four times; in general a power of two will result in n*2-1 calls.

Also note that by just calling pow(x, n/2) once and squaring the result in that branch, the algorithm becomes O(log n).

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking at the Master Theorem a bit and I'm trying to wrap my head around it... guess I'll have to give it a bit more thought!

Comment: Don't feel too bad -- it's one of the hardest bits you need in the runtime analysis of most common-case code you see.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define f(m) as that it gives you the number of operations of a problem with size m. The 'problem' is of course exponentiation (pow), like `x^n` or `pow(x,n)`. The `long pow( long x, int n ) {` function does not need to do more or less work if I change x. So, the size of the problem exponentiation does not depend on x. It does however depend on n. Let's say 2^4 is of size 4 and 3^120 is of size 120. (Makes sense if you see that `2^4=2*2*2*2` and `3^120=3*3*3*3*..*3`) The problem size is thus equal to `n`, the second parameter. We could, if you want, say the problem size is 2*log(n), but that would be silly.

Now we have f(m) is the number of operations to calculate `pow(x,m)` for any x. Because `pow(x,m)` is exactly the problem with size m. **So, if we have `pow(x,y)` then the number of operations is, by definition, `f(y)`.** For example,  `pow(3,3*m/2)` has `f(3*m/2)` operations.

Finally, let's count the operations

```
long pow( long x, int n ) {
    if (n == 0)  //1
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)  //1
    return x;
    if(isEven(n)) //1
        return pow(x, n / 2 ) * //that is f(n/2), y=n / 2
                 pow(x, n / 2); //also f(n/2)
    else
        return x * pow(x * x, n / 2); //1+1+f(n/2)
}
```

Taking it together: `f(n) = 2*f(n/2) + c1` (n even) and `f(n) = f(n/2) + c2` (n odd). If you are only interested in the worst case scenario, then note that the odd case is less work. Thus f(n) is bounded above by the even case: `f(n) <= 2*f(n/2)+c`.