# Calculating time complexity in case of recursion algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time, time-complexity, heapsort

How do you calculate time complexity in case of recursion algorithms?

for eg t(n) = t(3n/2) + 0(1)   (Heapsort)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709106/time-complexity-of-a-recursive-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master's theorm is the quick and short way. But since you are trying to learn the complexity for all recursive functions, I would rather suggest  you to learn the working of recursion tree, which forms the foundation of Master's Theorm . This [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=proof%20for%20masters%20theorem&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf&ei=rmmxTqDTE6HU2AW7l8XAAw&usg=AFQjCNGDmkEB1d_ClcH6IryDb3TB8kEN8Q&sig2=tzsKR1FJEg0rz950xywrjQ&cad=rja) goes on to explain it in detail. Rather than using the Master's theorm blindly, learn this for your better understanding in the future ! This [link about recursion tree](http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C455/html/notes/Chapter4/RecursionTree.htm) is a good read too

Comment: First link is http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=proof%20for%20masters%20theorem&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf&ei=rmmxTqDTE6HU2AW7l8XAAw&usg=AFQjCNGDmkEB1d_ClcH6IryDb3TB8kEN8Q&sig2=tzsKR1FJEg0rz950xywrjQ&cad=rja

Second link is http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C455/html/notes/Chapter4/RecursionTree.htm

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Anyway, your equation looks broken, since recursive calls have higher input values than that of the caller, so your complexity is **O(infinity)**.

Please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

usually you can guess the answer and use induction to prove it.

but there is a theorem which solves a lot of situations as heap sort, named Master Theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0):

[Complexity of Heapsort](http://www.cs.txstate.edu/~ch04/webtest/teaching/courses/5329/lectures/heap-comp.pdf)