# Analysis of a specific algorithm running time with recursion

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

How would I go about calculating the runtime of this algorithm, so I can solve similar questions in the future?

> For input size n satisfies the recurrence relation (for n>= 1)

```
T(n) = (2/n) * (T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-1)) + 5n
```

Comment: This [Tutorial](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html) will help you. It explains clearly each and every step.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! But I am still struggling with the format, How do I start this analysis, the "..." is throwing me off.

Comment: Start considering n=5,6,7.., then you might end up solving what you need :)

Comment: Do I just write the first case as (2/n)(T(n-1)+5)?

Comment: No, I meant T(5) = (2/5)*(T(0)+T(1)+T(2)+T(3)+T(4)) + 5*5, Or else consider T(3) for even more easier analysis and understand how time is being calculated

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709106/time-complexity-of-a-recursive-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to get rid of sums is to compute differences, after multiplying by $n$ (allow me to write LaTeX, even if this site doesn't use it; I hope the formulas are understandable):

$$
(n + 1) a_{n + 1} - n a_n
  = 2 a_n + 5
$$

$$
(n + 1) a_{n + 1} - (n + 2) a_n = 5
$$

This is a linear recurrence of the first order. A recurrence of the form:

$$
x_n - u_{n - 1} x_{n - 1} = f_n
$$

can be reduced to a sum by dividing by the *summing factor* $S_n = \prod_{0 \le k \le n} u_n$ to get:

$$
\frac{x_n}{S_n} - \frac{x_{n - 1}}{S_{n - 1}} = \frac{f_n}{S_n}
$$

Summing over $1 \le n \le N$ gives a solution to the equation.

In your particular case $S_n = \prod_{0 \le k \le n} \frac{n + 2}{n + 1} = n + 1$, so that:

$$
\frac{a_{k + 1}}{k + 2} - \frac{a_k}{k + 1} = \frac{5}{(k + 1) (k + 2)}
$$

\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{n + 1} - \frac{a_0}{1} 
  &= 5 \sum_{0 \le k < n} \frac{1}{(k + 1) (k + 2} \
  &= - 5 \sum_{0 \le k < n} \left( \frac{1}{k + 2} - \frac{1}{k + 1} \right) \
  &= - 5 \left( \frac{1}{n + 1} - 1 \right) \
  &= 5 \frac{n}{n + 1} 
\end{align}

Finally:

$$
a_n = a_0 (n + 1) + 5 n
$$