# compute time complexity on recursive function

Tags: algorithm

I read about time complexity and how to compute it. But most of the examples are about for loops, and not comes with recursion.
Could anyone use [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/45graph/AllPaths.java.html) algorithm as an example? I want to know time complexity when it comes with recursion.
That algorithm is to find all simple paths between two points. I see somewhere its time complexity is O(n!), am I right? can someone explain me how O(n!) is computed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time complexity of a recursive algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709106/time-complexity-of-a-recursive-algorithm)

Comment: The so-called [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) covers the analysis of some typical cases of recursion.

Comment: @u_seem_surprised.  I think you saying is for DFS, here that algorithm to find simple paths. I guess its time complexity is not O(V+E). I guess it is O(N!). I want to know how to conclude its time comlexity

Comment: @alim Yes, you are right i missed the part where the code does `path.pop();`, thereby enumerating all possible paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to take a stab at this. I'm assuming each node is connected to every other node, since I think that would assist me in establishing the worst case situation. Say, we have 5 nodes in a graph [A,B,C,D,E]; so, `n=5`. In the worst case, each of the `n` nodes have `n-1` neighbors.

How many options do I have to choose the first point? 5.

After picking the first point, how many ways to choose the next point? 4

Do you see a pattern? (Consider the pushing and popping)

Since, you want to consider all the possible points, you must touch each node at least once, for every path consideration.

So, we have `n` choices to pick the first node, `n-1` to pick the second and so on, which results in the `n!` number of possible paths, so `n!` "visits" to each node, using an (un-optimized) algorithm.

Comment: Great, that is much clear. By the way, what is time complexity of possible optimized version of this algorithm? It seems there are not much to do with that algorithm.

Comment: @alim What I meant was if you use some sort of a caching mechanism to store sub-paths from nodes. For instance, say you are aware of the sub-path C-D-E. Then, if you already computed this in the instance when you started from A, you don't have to recompute this for B. This was a very rudimentary and inelegant example. But, I guess you will get the idea.