# Time complexity of a recursive function containing for loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity(O) of this function? I have mergesort and binary search in my code as well. I know binary search is O(log n) and mergesort is O(nlogn) but what is the complexity of this algorithm?

```
import os

mydatafile = open("myss.csv","w+")
def rec(searchpath):
    if os.path.isdir(searchpath):
        for i in os.listdir(searchpath):
            childpath = os.path.join(searchpath,i)
            if not os.path.isdir(childpath):
                mydata = i + ", " + childpath + "\n"
                mydatafile.write(mydata)
            else:
                mydata = i + ", " + childpath + "\n"
                mydatafile.write(mydata)
                rec(childpath)
rec("C:\Python27")
mydatafile.close()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709106/time-complexity-of-a-recursive-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The I/O functions somewhat mask the input. You might think that the name of the root directory `searchpath` is the input, but it's more reasonable to think of the input as being the rooted tree that represents the the directory hierarchy. Assuming (again, reasonably) that a constant amount of work is done at each node, the running time is just O(n).

Comment: So it means my time complexity will be nlogn for my whole code since i have mergesort and binarysearch as well?

Comment: That depends on what you are sorting and searching. If you sort the resulting data file once (or at most a constant number of times), that's still O(n lg n). Each binary search is O(lg n), so if you do `k` searches (where `k` and `n` are independent), you end up with O(n lg n + k lg n). (Which basically says that the total running time is bounded whichever takes longer, the sorting or the searching.)